# Bootstrap Icon Fading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-icons

I'm wondering how to display the filled version of a bootstrap icon when I hover over it.

I have this code:

```html
<svg
  width="80px"
  height="80px"
  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
  class="bi bi-cloud-plus"
  fill="#5cb85c"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <path
    fill-rule="evenodd"
    d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383zm.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z"
  />
  <path
    fill-rule="evenodd"
    d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"
  />
</svg>
```

(cloud plus icon)
and I'm wondering how to merge it to it's filled partner (cloud plus fill icon). How?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about how StackOverflow works (you even get a badge!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way this is accomplished is to:

1. Include both elements in your markup (in this case, both the filled and non-filled version), with a common parent.
2. Hide the fill version with CSS
3. On `:hover` of the parent, swap the CSS to hide the non-filled version and show the filled version.

See below:

```css
.icon-wrapper .bi-cloud-plus-fill {
  display: none;
}

.icon-wrapper:hover .bi-cloud-plus-fill {
  display: inline;
}

.icon-wrapper:hover .bi-cloud-plus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cloud-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383zm.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
  </svg>
  
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cloud-plus-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 6.095 0 7.555 0 9.318 0 11.366 1.708 13 3.781 13h8.906C14.502 13 16 11.57 16 9.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 3.999 10.69 2 8 2zm.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v1.5H6a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.5V10a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8.5H10a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H8.5V6z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

To do a transition between them is possible but a bit more difficult, in that it requires some positioning tricks.  We have to make the parent `position: relative;` so that the children can be `position: absolute` to sit on top of each other.  Then, instead of leveraging `display` we leverage `opacity` for showing/hiding, and put a `transition` for the `opacity` property:

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  position: relative
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-wrapper .bi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.icon-wrapper .bi-cloud-plus-fill {
  opacity: 0;
}

.icon-wrapper .bi-cloud-plus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon-wrapper:hover .bi-cloud-plus-fill {
  opacity: 1
}

.icon-wrapper:hover .bi-cloud-plus {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cloud-plus" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383zm.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
  </svg>
  
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cloud-plus-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 6.095 0 7.555 0 9.318 0 11.366 1.708 13 3.781 13h8.906C14.502 13 16 11.57 16 9.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 3.999 10.69 2 8 2zm.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v1.5H6a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.5V10a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8.5H10a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H8.5V6z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

One last thing-- these SVG are not particularly accessible by themselves.  Consider leveraging [Bootstrap screen reader utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/screenreaders/) to add some accessible text for users who may not be looking at your site to navigate it.

Comment: Why do you need the various CDN links? Your code will work fine without them.

Comment: This works, but can these possibly fade into each other?

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 - good catch-- I removed them.  Bootstrap generally has so much "magic" running under the hood, I included them in case it was applying any specific styles to the icon classes.  But you're correct- they were superfluous.

Comment: @BumpyDevelopment - yeah, give me a second to do an edit-- this too should be able to be accomplished w/ CSS, although it's a bit trickier with the positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, and change the `innerHTML` of the icon based on if it's being hovered over or not.

```js
 
document.getElementById('cloud-plus').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  this.innerHTML = `<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 2a5.53 5.53 0 0 0-3.594 1.342c-.766.66-1.321 1.52-1.464 2.383C1.266 6.095 0 7.555 0 9.318 0 11.366 1.708 13 3.781 13h8.906C14.502 13 16 11.57 16 9.773c0-1.636-1.242-2.969-2.834-3.194C12.923 3.999 10.69 2 8 2zm.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v1.5H6a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.5V10a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V8.5H10a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H8.5V6z"/>`
})

document.getElementById('cloud-plus').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  this.innerHTML = `<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383zm.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z" />
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />`
})
```

```html
<svg id="cloud-plus" width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cloud-plus" fill="#5cb85c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> // I added id of "cloud-plus" to element
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383zm.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z" />
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />
</svg>
```